# Can't create Firebase project - There was an unknown error while processing the request. Try again

Tags: firebase

I'm trying to create new project in Firebase but every time I'm getting this error

> There was an unknown error while processing the request. Try again.

I have tried to log out and log in but it doesn't work.

[image]

How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At time of writing, Google Cloud Platform (and by extension, Firebase) is experiencing an incident that prevents new projects from being created.
See the links below:

https://status.cloud.google.com/incident/developers-console/17007
https://status.firebase.google.com/incident/Console/17026

Comment: Is there a way to be notified when it is fixed?

Answer (score 1):

This is because your package name is Already registered in Firebase even if it is deleted, Change the package name and it will start working.