# How do I get past this error in the Firebase console when adding a new app? "There was an unknown error while processing the request. Try again."

Tags: firebase, google-analytics

I'm getting this error after I try to add a new app and click 'Register App':

"There was an unknown error while processing the request. Try again."

I've looked at these and they have the same problem but didn't have solutions that worked:

[Can't create Firebase project - There was an unknown error while processing the request. Try again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46554378/cant-create-firebase-project-there-was-an-unknown-error-while-processing-the)

[GCM - Getting Error message "There was an unknown error while processing the request. Try again." when creating new project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36000242/gcm-getting-error-message-there-was-an-unknown-error-while-processing-the-req)

[Firebase: There was an unknown error while processing the request. Try again.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43115090/firebase-there-was-an-unknown-error-while-processing-the-request-try-again)

I'm not using multiple Google accounts. I've tried signing out and in again, tried changing the package name, and the Firebase status page doesn't show any outages.

Comment: Did you try clearing the browser's cache?

Comment: @jackz314 yes and I've used two different browsers.

Comment: Could you try opening your browsers console and network tab and check what the server returns on your request to add a new app? From what I can tell, it should be a call to `/v1/projects/{projectId}/clients`. The response may have a more detailed error code.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, After a long research fond that it was been **OAuth 2.0 Client Id limit**. In order to resolve, I have deleted all **OAuth 2.0 Client IDs** from Google cloud console, then try again. It works fine for me.

Steps to remove OAuth 2.0 Client IDs :

1. Open 'https://console.cloud.google.com/'
2. Select your **project** from the top navbar
3. Select **APIs & Services** from Left Side panel
4. Select **Credentials** in the left panel
5. Go to **OAuth 2.0 Client IDs**
6. Select **all unused Entries** (!Carefully)
7. Click on **delete** on the top bar
8. **Done**, go to firebase console try again

It may solve your problem!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing your package name? I'd same issue,that was resolved by changing package name. As Firebase saves deleted package names as well.

Answer (score 0):

You might reached number of **OAuth 2.0 client IDs** limits. There is a limit of around 30 client IDs that can be created within a single project.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you sign out all your google accounts and sign in with the account for your specific project. I'm normally signed in to 3 or 4 accounts and ran into this error issue. Did as I mentioned and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The operation has failed (Reason: [object ProgressEvent])

I am getting the above-mentioned error while creating a new project. This got resolved by logging out and logging in again

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue. I just waited a few minutes and tried again and it worked this time.

Answer (score 0):

My problem solved when i changed my VPN.